# Bash If else Read from file

Tags: bash, if-statement, parameters

The goal here is when parameters $AutoBasher is set read from file line by line then take that variable and add it to a curl command. I also tried to have it when the parameters is set then run this command, if not then this command. Id like the script to run a one automated command, if not then run command with $URL.

```
AutoBasher()
{
  if [[ -z "$AutoBasher" ]]; then
    echo ''
  else  
    for FileLine in $AutoBasher; do
      while IFS= `read -r Line`; do
    echo ${Line}
      done < "FileLine" 
    done < "$AutoBasher"
  fi
}
curl $(AutoBasher)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're declaring a function `AutoBasher` that doesn't get called anywhere, you're calling to functions `AccessVerb` and `AccessHeader` that I don't see anywhere, `AutoBasher` also seems to be a variable that contains multiple filenames, and for each of these names, you're looping over the filename of that line and echo its contents? If `AutoBasher` gets called, which it doesn't?

Comment: You can't "read" from the file defined by `$AutoBasher` both with `< $AutoBasher` and `for FileLine in ${AutoBasher}`.  You want `while read FileLine ; do ... ; done < $AutoBasher`. Hmm, and you have a 2ndary loop, The `read` can't process std-in from 2 separate files. you'll need to search here for correct syntax. Something about `exec 4>&1` or slimilar. Good luck.

Comment: @BenjaminW. those are else where in the script i tried to avoid pasting the whole script in here. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @shellter I appreciate your advice it works thank you =]

Comment: Ideally, the code you post would be complete (self-contained) and expose the specific problem you have, see [mcve].